# "Vital aspect" or "vital goal" - which is correct in this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Which sentence below makes the most sense?

1. Showing care for those in need is a vital aspect of our organization's programs.
2. Showing care for those in need is a vital goal of our organization's programs.

The organization in the above sentences is a charity.

Does "aspect" make sense here? If not, can I please be provided a reason as to why?

Comment: I would go back and reconsider "showing care" first.

Comment: Kudos to those who "Show care for those in need" as a program aspect, over those who don't, but claim that care as a lofty, vital goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences make perfect sense regarding the use of "aspect" or "goal", they just mean different things. I agree with the comment, I would either start the sentence with *Caring for those in need* or *Providing care for those in need*.

If you use *aspect*, you are saying that providing care *characterises* everything the organization does, all its programs. Though it is a vital aspect, it is still less strong than ***vital goal***, which implies that this is the motivation for all these programs.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aspect) explains *aspect* as meaning:

> ***one part of*** a situation, problem, subject, etc.

whereas *goal* means

> the result or achievement toward which effort is directed. ([Dict.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/goal))

So while *aspect* is part of one's efforts, *goal* is the target of those efforts. The word nearer the truth makes more sense, so you must assess the situation and choose.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that "aspect" makes more sense, because showing care is an attitude, not a feat which one must work to achieve (ie. a goal). It might make sense to say "providing care is a goal", because there might be financial, organisational etc. challenges to overcome in order to provide care (eg. medical assistance, food handouts), but if by showing care you simply mean displaying concern, then aspect would be more appropriate.